# Recover oracle database using archived logs created after the backup

Tags: oracle

I take a daily backup of my Oracle production database. The backup is created using RMAN and includes control files and archived logs up to the point the backup was taken. For disaster recovery purposes, I want to test the restore of the backup to a new server. (The production database will remain fully operational throughout.)

My question is: when I restore the backup and recover the database on the new server, is it possible to further recover it beyond the archived logs contained in the backup, by using additional archived logs that have been created on the production database since the backup was taken? If so, how would I go about this?

Comment: If those archivelogs are still available after the disaster scenario, you could copy them over.  If you copy them into the same directory path name as their original location (so that they are where the control file expects them to be) then it should work.   It will depend on the details of how you took your backup, and the nature of the recovery.   There are various recovery scenarios detailed in the Backup and Recovery User's Guide.

Comment: Step 01: Restore database from backup to new machine (don't recover)! Step 02: Copy all archive log appear after backup in step 01 (guarantee no missing archive) to a directory Step 03: Using rman> catalog start with '<directoryOfArchive>'; point to archive dictory. Step 04: Recover datase until cancel! Then Open DB resetlogs - DB will go as far as your archive can be.